# android room ORM after have initial values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

In Android ORM how can I add some initial values in tables in SQLite I usually do this in onCreate of SQLite.
But on room how can I do this mean after creation on database adds some initial values.
thank you for your answer.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62185732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using RoomDatabase.Callback which is available in the latest version of Room library.

You need to implement onCreate and onOpen method of RoomDatabase.Callback and add it to RoomDatabase.Builder as shown below.

**RoomDatabase.Callback**

```
  RoomDatabase.Callback rdc = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        public void onCreate (SupportSQLiteDatabase db){
        // do something after database has been created
        }
        public void onOpen (SupportSQLiteDatabase db){
        //do something every time database is open
        }
    };
```

**Adding callback to room database builder**

```
 yourDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                            YourDatabase.class, "your db").addCallback(rdc).build();
```

Reference : https://medium.com/@srinuraop/database-create-and-open-callbacks-in-room-7ca98c3286ab

Comment: how // do something after db has been created, should look like in your opinion. If we use db.insert( ...) we lose type safety that Room provides when we access it via DAOs. If we get instance of database to get DAO and insert via it, recursive calls of onCreate() are triggered. Is there 3rd solution?